# No appropriate default constructor available in struct with glm vectors

Tags: c++, default-constructor, glm-math

in .h:

```
enum collisionType {AB, BA, AoverB, AunderB};

struct Collision {
public:
    collisionType type;
    glm::vec2 point1;
    glm::vec2 point2;

    Collision(enum collisionType, glm::vec2, glm::vec2);
};
```

in .cpp:

```
Collision::Collision(enum collisionType collisType, glm::vec2 p1, glm::vec2 p2) : type(collisType), point1(p1), point2(p2)
{

}
```

using it

```
std::vector<Collision> collisions;

glm::vec2 point1(11.0, 12.0);
glm::vec2 point2(12.0, 13.0);

collisions.push_back(Collision(AoverB, point1, point2));
```

Getting error C2512: 'Collision' : no appropriate default constructor available, why?

Comment: The snippet above compiles just well on g++. Are you sure you you dont use `Collision a;` or smth somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) the requirements for a type `T` to be well suited for `std::vector`.
Default-constructible is not listed there.

I also tried compiling this minimal code sample, in which X doesn't have a default constructor, and it compiles fine with MSVC:

```
#include <vector>

struct X {
    X(int a, int b) : A(a), B(b) {}
    int A;
    int B;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<X> v;
    v.push_back(X(10,20));
}
```

So, the problem must be elsewhere in your code.

Anyway, you may want to add a constructor with no arguments to make your Collission class "default-constructible", and make the compiler happy:

```
struct Collision {

    // Default constructor.
    // Initialize data members to some init values.
    Collision() {
        ...
    }
```

---

**PS** Note that `struct` in C++ is equivalent to `class { public: ...`, so you can omit the `public:` line in your code: it's implied by the use of the keyword `struct`.

Comment: It says nothing about default-constructible. Only CopyAssignable and CopyConstructible, or MoveAssignable and MoveConstructible since c++11.

Comment: @BlazBratanic: Thanks, I've updated my answer. I also tested that std::vector and push_back seem to work correctly with classes that are not deafult-constructible. The OP's problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The following code compiles fine, it's something else that is the problem.

```
#include <glm/vec2.hpp>
#include <vector>

enum collisionType {AB, BA, AoverB, AunderB};

struct Collision {
public:
    collisionType type;
    glm::vec2 point1;
    glm::vec2 point2;

    Collision(enum collisionType, glm::vec2, glm::vec2);
};

Collision::Collision(enum collisionType collisType, glm::vec2 p1, glm::vec2 p2) : type(collisType), point1(p1), point2(p2)
{

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Collision> collisions;

    glm::vec2 point1(11.0, 12.0);
    glm::vec2 point2(12.0, 13.0);

    collisions.push_back(Collision(AoverB, point1, point2));
}
```